# ExecuteSQL processor returns corrupted data

Tags: hive, apache-nifi

I have a flow in NiFI in which I use the ExecuteSQL processor to get a whole a merge of sub-partitions named dt from a `hive` table. For example: My table is partitioned by `sikid` and `dt`. So I have under `sikid=1, dt=1000`, and under `sikid=2, dt=1000`.
What I did is `select * from my_table where dt=1000`.

Unfortunately, what I've got in return from the ExecuteSQL processor is corrupted data, including rows that have `dt=NULL` while the original table does not have even one row with dt=NULL.

The `DBCPConnectionPool` is configured to use `HiveJDBC4` jar. 
Later I tried using the compatible jar according to the CDH release, didn't fix it either.

The `ExecuteSQL` processor is configured as such:

`Normalize Table/Column Names`: `true`

`Use Avro Logical Types`: `false`

Hive version: 1.1.0

CDH: 5.7.1

Any ideas what's happening? Thanks!

EDIT:
Apparently my returned data includes extra rows... a few thousand of them.. which is quite weird.

Comment: quite sure that's a problem from jdbc driver. could you check what result set returned by other jdbc-based tools. for example you could take [squirrel-sql](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) and try execute the same query.

Comment: You might also want to try SelectHiveQL instead of ExecuteSQL, the former has the Hive 1.2.1 driver included already, the latter doesn't "officially" support Hive, even with a third-party driver

Comment: @daggett good point, I didn't try to change driver. I'm currently using `HiveJDBC4` but I'll try a different version.

Comment: @mattyb Actually I've tried using `hive-nar` at first but I've had problems using it regarding my authentication method in my hadoop cluster and hive. So I rather use the ExecuteSQL processor so it would be generic too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually it was solved by using hive property `hive.query.result.fileformat=SequenceFile`

Answer (score 0):

Does `HiveJDBC4` (I assume the Simba Hive driver) parse the table name off the column names? This was one place there was an incompatibility with the Apache Hive JDBC driver, it didn't support `getTableName()` so doesn't work with ExecuteSQL, and even if it did, when the column names are retrieved from the ResultSetMetaData, they had the table names prepended with a period `.` separator. This is some of the custom code that is in HiveJdbcCommon (used by SelectHiveQL) vs JdbcCommon (used by ExecuteSQL).

If you're trying to use ExecuteSQL because you had trouble with the authentication method, how is that alleviated with the Simba driver? Do you specify auth information on the JDBC URL rather than in a hive-site.xml file for example? If you ask your auth question (using SelectHiveQL) as a separate SO question and link to it here, I will do my best to help out on that front and get you past this.

Comment: Actually yes, it converts it to `my_table_columnName`.
I might really open a question about the problems I'm having with Hive.. Thanks
I tried switching from `HiveJDBC4` to `hivejdbc-1.2.1` but unfortunately it didn't help...

Comment: ID: 50857966 Thanks :)

Comment: well, I've tried to use the jar placed in one of my datanodes, it seems that now the schema extracted out of the data consists the correct column names(`columnName` instead of `tableName_columnName`) but data is still returned corrupted.. I have over 4000 rows with `dt is null`..

Comment: Got a solution :)