# nifi - SelectHiveQL returns Cannot create PoolableCOnnectionFactory

Tags: hive, apache-nifi

I'm trying to transfer from `ExecuteSQL` to `SelectHiveQL` but when a FlowFile reaches `SelectHiveQL` it fails with `Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not establish conection to jdbc:hive2://<server>:<port>/<db>;auth=noSasl;mapreduce.map.meory.mb=4000: null). No FlowFile to route to failure...`
And deletes my FlowFile. The `DBCPConnectionPool` is configured the same but it works(but returns corrupted data). 
It's not just strange because it doesn't work, it's also strange because it just deletes the FlowFile instead of routing it to failure.

Partial stack trace:
`at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
......
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://<server>:<port>/<db>;auth=noSasl;mapreduce.map.memory.mb=4000: null
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:594)
...
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPolableCOnectionFactory(BASicDataSource.java:1545)
....
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: null
at org.apache.thrit.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java: 132)
.....
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HIveCOnection.openSession(HiveCOnnection.java:583)`

NiFi Version: `1.6.0`(although it didn't work in 1.4.0 either)

Java Version: `1.8.0_121`

Hive Version: `1.1.0-cdh5.7.1`

Any help? Thanks..

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace from the logs? Usually the real reason is hidden further down the stack

Comment: @mattyb added..

Comment: What version of NiFi (Apache or otherwise) and what version/vendor of Hive are you using?

Comment: @mattyb added too

Comment: @mattyb Anything?

Answer (score 0):

The version of Hive in NiFi is based on 1.2.1, which is not compatible with 1.1.0. I believe you were seeking an alternative by using a Simba driver and the non-Hive processors like ExecuteSQL, I haven’t tried that so I’m not sure if that’s a valid workaround or not.

Comment: Actually, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792317/executesql-processor-returns-corrupted-data

Comment: I didn’t see the errors above in the other description, that’s why I asked. The two Hive differences are usually enough to preclude use of NiFi for CDH based on 1.1.x